# what is the difference between these two a = 'abc'; var b = 'abc';

Tags: javascript

The difference between these two lines of code?

```
a = 'abc'; 

var b = 'abc';
```

Are they just different variables? is that it?

I want to say it is but I am just learning.

Comment: You should check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one implicitly creates a global variable and the second one creates a variable in the current scope.

Comment: Thank you!  This would also apply to const correct? since Const replaced Var? and why would one be better than the other?

Comment: No, `const` did not replace `var`. `const` is a different way of declaring a variable as a "constant", once it's set the value can't be changed.

Comment: The value of a const can be changed, but the reference cannot. example `const a = { b: 'c' };
a.d = 'f';` is completely fine, whereas 
`a = 2;` will throw an arrow (because you are changing its reference)

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

On global scope wise there is no difference. However, if you are on local scope there is a difference.

```
//Both global
var test1=1;
test2=2;

function first()
{
    var test1 =-1; // Local: set a new variable independent of the global test1
    test2 =3;     // Change the test2 global variable to 2
    console.log(test1); //will display -1 (local variable value)
}
function second()
{
   console.log(test1); //will display 1 (global variable value)
}
```

Inside `function first()` the value of test1 is -1 because we test1 is hitting the local variable created using `var`, `function second()` has no test1 as a local variable so it will display 1.